# TopologyException error during fortify SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: polygon, r, error, topology, ggplot2

I tried to reproduce a recent question on [spatial data visualization using **ggplot2**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/145146/plotting-data-without-geographical-coordinates-besides-the-main-map-in-ggplot2) and received the following error message during `fortify(world, region = "ISO3")`:

```
Error: TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 
3980740.7660219339 4277735.2740812832 at 3980740.7660219339 4277735.2740812832
```

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment in that question, it's to do with the `spTransform`. Simply remove the offending line:

```
world <- spTransform(world, CRS("+proj=robin"))
```

Comment: So it's simply the projection that is not suited for world-wide data?

Comment: As far as I can tell it's the Robinson projection which is suitable for mapping the world: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_projection I suspect transforming the polygons is causing overlap